# How do you make a collection from a hash table?

Tags: java, collections, hashtable

I am wondering just what the generic code for making a Collection out of a Hash Table would look like. For example if I already have a Hash Table created, how would I then convert that to a collection?

Comment: Look at the javadoc before you post here -- in this case, either HashTable.entrySet() or HashTable.values().

Comment: What elements in the HashTable are you expecting to put into the Collection?  The Keys And the Values?  Just the Values?

Comment: I was looking at the javadoc all day and those slipped right past me, thanks for pointing them out. And I want to put both keys and the values into the collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of converting a `Hashtable<String, String>` to a `HashMap<String, String>` (which is part of [Collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html))

```
    Hashtable<String, String> ht = new Hashtable<String, String>();
    ht.put("key1", "value1");
    ht.put("key2", "value2");
    ht.put("key3", "value3");

    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();

    for (String key : ht.keySet()) {
        map.put(key, ht.get(key));
    }

    for (String key : map.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(key+"\t"+map.get(key));
    }
```

It should be noted that this code generates an `Obsolete Collection` warning.